# Ubuntu Stuck On Purple Screen

Tags: dual-boot, radeon, hp, initramfs

I have a HP Dv6. I have had Ubuntu installed on the dual boot for some time. Its along side windows 7. I have not booted Ubuntu for quite some time as I have not needed it. Today I decided to boot it, up and I'm stuck on this purple screen. This has not happened before.

After reading some posts I'm sort of confused. Upon boot I hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key a menu comes up the second option is `recovery mode`. I enter and then some lines of code run for a while near the end this is the output:

```
BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

whatever I do I do not wish to loose anything from my windows 7 or Ubuntu as I have stuff in both places.

My laptop has a Radeon Graphics card, I've read some posts that the graphics card can be the problem